# Stop-AzureRmWebApp - Looked Dlls

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am traying to deploy a web application using FTP, but sometimes a get "Looked DLL" errors even if the webapp was stopped using Stop-AzureRmWebApp. So, a think the files are been used until the webapp is fully stopped, there is any way to use FTP and avoid this issue?

Comment: What's the detail  failed log info. Could you provide failed part here better with `system.debug=true`? Besides, since you have mentioned "sometimes", is it a problem occur  randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are dealing with locked files during deployment then check out this wiki " [Dealing with locked files during deployment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Dealing-with-locked-files-during-deployment)" which can provide you with some more insight.

To determining what's causing the file to be locked, use the Kudu process explorer. To access it:

-Go to Kudu, and click on Process Explorer in the top bar.

-Looking at the process list, you may already be able to guess which one is likely to lock the file. You can try clicking 'Find Handle' at the top and searching for the file name. Note that this will not include loaded DLLs.

-You can also right-click on a process and choose Properties. From here, you can get a list of both loaded modules (typically DLLs), and file handles. For multiple instances, since any instance can lock the file, you will need to iterate Kudu instances from dropdown and check.

Also, you may want to try deploying to a [staging slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) with [auto swap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#configure-auto-swap) enable.

Comment: Thanks to every one, finally, I changed my pipelines to use the Kudu rest Api, and for the moment all problems are gone.